# twitter data cleaning in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

Below is my work.

```
tweets <- searchTwitter("urban park", n = 2000, lang = "en")
tweets <- strip_retweets(tweets)
text <- sapply(tweets, function(x) x$getText())
text <- gsub("&amp", "", text)
text <- gsub("http\\w+", "", text)
text <- gsub("@\\w+", "", text)
text <- gsub('[[:punct:]]', '', text)
text <- gsub('[[:cntrl:]]', '', text)
text <- gsub("[[:digit:]]", "", text)
text <- gsub("[ \t]{2,}", "", text)
text <- gsub("^\\s+|\\s+$", "", text)
mycorpus <- Corpus(VectorSource(text))
inspect(mycorpus[35:50])
```

Results: ......

```
[22] skateboard skate board scene skate park urban worn street streetlife eauclaire… tcoFvJllsRC

[23] skateboard skate board scene skate park urban worn street streetlife eauclaire… tcoBRbDKOxOs

[24] skateboard skate board scene skate park urban worn street streetlife eauclaire… tcoxlUFDOudRm ......
```

Although I've used the function strip_retweets to remove those retweets before cleaning the text, retweets still here as shown above.

Also, how can I remove those words like "tcoFvJllsRC", "tcoxlUFDOudRm"? What are they stand for?

Are my text cleaning processes correct?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Exclude scraping retweets with twitteR in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41164121/exclude-scraping-retweets-with-twitter-in-r)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I find the [rtweet](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rtweet/vignettes/intro.html) package much easier to work with than `twitteR`, which is no longer up to date.

```
library(rtweet)
tweets <- search_tweets("urban park", n = 2000, lang = "en", full_text = TRUE)
```

This returns a data frame. One of the column names is `is_retweet`, which makes filtering for retweets easy. Or just use `include_rts = FALSE` in `search_tweets()`.

```
library(dplyr)
tweets <- tweets %>%
  filter(is_retweet == FALSE)
```

I normally use the [tidytext](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/tidytext/) package for text analysis. For example, to split tweet text into words, filter for words that you don't want and remove common "stop words":

```
tweets <- tweets %>% 
  filter(is_retweet == FALSE) %>%
  select(text) %>%
  unnest_tokens(word, text) %>% 
  select(word) %>% 
  filter(!word %in% c("https", "t.co", "amp"),   # and whatever else to ignore
         !word %in% tolower(tweets$screen_name), # remove user names
         !grepl("^\\d+$", word)) %>%             # remove numbers      
  anti_join(stop_words)
```

Comment: So should I use tm_map to do stem completion? Or there is another set of code to do the stem completion. (I'd like to clean the twitter data to generate wordcloud, to analyze the relationship between words, and to sentiment analysis, so I need to do stem completion process first)

Answer (score 2):

You shld accept @neilfws's answer. This is just a nice cleaning function to add to it:

```
clean_tweet_text <- function(x) {

  require(stringi)

  c(
    url_pattern = "http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\\(\\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+",
    handle_pattern = "(^|[^@[:word:]])@([:word:]{1,15})\b",
    entity_pattern = "&[^[:space:]]*;",
    other_pattern = "[[:punct:][:cntrl:][:digit:]]",
    twitter_hashtag_regex <- "(^|[^&\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{Nd}_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7])(#|\uFF03)(?!\uFE0F|\u20E3)([\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{Nd}_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7]*[\\p{L}\\p{M}][\\p{L}\\p{M}\\p{Nd}_\u200c\u200d\ua67e\u05be\u05f3\u05f4\u309b\u309c\u30a0\u30fb\u3003\u0f0b\u0f0c\u00b7]*)"
  ) -> pats

  pats <- sprintf("(%s)", paste0(pats, collapse="|"))

  x <- stri_replace_all_regex(x, pats, "")
  x <- stri_trim_both(x)

  x

}
```